# jquery mousenter, mouseleave and overlay

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

)I looked at messages here about this issue and tried a lot of the found suggestions with no success:

I would like to append an overlay on mousentering an article but I would like to remove this overlay by mouseleaving this very overlay and prevent it to append again unless I re-enter the article again with my mouse.

The issue right now is that when the overlay disappears, the mouse being suddenly on the article is making the overlay reappear instantly, which is very logic.
result: it flickers like hell.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Thank you

```
$('.article').mouseenter(function(){ 

    var xx=$(window).width();

    if (!$('boxOverlay').length) {
        $('body').append('<div class="boxOverlay"></div>');
        $('.boxOverlay').css({
            'height': $(window).height(),
            'display': 'block',
            'position': 'fixed',
            'z-index': '99',
            'width': '1050px',
            'margin-left': (xx-1050)/2,
        });
    }

    $('.boxOverlay').mouseleave(function(){
      $('.boxOverlay').remove()  
    })
});
```

I tried with hover (with two contrary functions in it) with no success.

Comment: Yes it's just a typo, thank you. The code doesn't have it. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.article').mouseleave(function(){
      $('.boxOverlay').remove()  
});
```

Now it will be work.

Comment: Well it's not. As I said, When the mouseleave is triggered, the overlay is removed and my mouse is now on the article again...which triggers the mouse enter event and opens the overlay immediately. It becomes a loop.